# Running a spring boot swing application from JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, process, command-prompt

I have an application which starts second spring boot application (which contains some Swing GUI) from java code using following code

```
  String cmd = "java -jar file.jar";
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

but when program executes this command, I can see the application starts in the task manager and it's GUI is visible. The weird thing is when I close the second application(using JFrame Exit feature) it does not get closed and it hangs until the first application is running.

The main problem is my second application is bound to my first application and it hangs until I closed the first application.

does anyone know how do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you mean _its GUI is **not** visible_?

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, question edited.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong, the terms calling application and caller application and main application all point to the same thing, did you mean _called_? In any case does the second application write anything to the output streams (standard or error stream)? In that case the problem might be one of you not properly consuming the application output.